# Using AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute to play from both ear piece and bottom speaker

Tags: ios, audio, avaudiosession

I am trying to figure out how to force audio to play through both the front earpiece and the bottom speaker in tandem using AVAudioSession and AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute on iOS.

I really *do not mind* if the solution is a hack, i know it has to be possible (even using private API) somehow so any method that gets me closer to pseudo-stereo audio would be a big help.

Just to note this is for educational purposes so theres no need worry about it being rejected.

```
NSError *error = nil;
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute error:&error];
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                         error:&error];
[session  overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&error];
```

This is where i am at with my investigation, further suggestions could include multiple AVAudioSessions' which are synced or something even more exotic.

Comment: I refuse to believe that there is nobody out there who has even the faintest suggestion as to which avenue of investigation i should go down... this is an interesting bit of work, it deserves discussion.

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question, but you helped me solve mine: this is how to get the audio to stay locally on the device even if the user activates screen mirroring